# Not able to post form data to action url

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I have a login form. After pressing the login button the the post data is sent to the view login_auth that authenticates the user data and redirects accordingly. However,after pressing the login button, I am not being redirected to the appropriate page.

views.py

```
def login_successful(request):
    return render(request,"login_successful.html")

def login_invalid(request):
    return render(request,"login_invalid.html")


def login(request):
    return render(request,'login.html',c)

def loginauth(request):
    username=request.POST.get("username",'')
    password=request.POST.get("password",'')
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not none:
        user.login(request.user)
        return redirect(login_successful)
    else:
        return redirect(login_invalid)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^registration/',views.registration),
url(r'^registration_successful/',views.registration_successful),
url(r'^home/',views.home),
url(r'^login/',views.login),

url(r'^login_successful/',views.login_successful),
url(r'^login_invalid/',views.login_invalid),
url(r'^login/auth',views.loginauth)
]
```

login.html

```
<html>
<form action="/login/auth" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

Username :<input type="textbox" name="username" >
Password :<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login">

</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login url pattern is missing a trailing `$`. It should be:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login),
```

Without the dollar, the `/login/auth` is matched by `r'^login/`, so the request is handled by your login view.

It's a bit unusual to process the form on a different url. Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), including a login view. I would recommend using this rather than writing your own.

Comment: thanks, it worked but could please tell my why it is unusual to process on a different url. Is there a security risk ?

Comment: There isn't a specific security risk of posting the login form to a different url. Usually, you would use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/). You display the form in the template, and use it in the view to process the data, so it makes sense to use the same view.

Answer (score 0):

Use **name** for url

views.py

```
def login_successful(request):
    return render(request,"login_successful.html")

def login_invalid(request):
    return render(request,"login_invalid.html")


def login(request):
    return render(request,'login.html',c)

def loginauth(request):
    username=request.POST.get("username",'')
    password=request.POST.get("password",'')
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not none:
        user.login(request.user)
        return redirect('login_successful')
    else:
        return redirect('login_invalid')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^registration/',views.registration),
url(r'^registration_successful/',views.registration_successful),
url(r'^home/',views.home),
url(r'^login/$',views.login),

url(r'^login_successful/',views.login_successful, name='login_successful'),
url(r'^login_invalid/',views.login_invalid, name='login_invalid'),
url(r'^login/auth',views.loginauth)
]
```